# add web shortuct on android desktop using Chrome (S4)

Tags: android, google-chrome, galaxy

I successfully managed to add on my android desktop a link to a web page.
I did that from Chrome, I added my url as a favourite, then from the favourite screen there is a link to add it on the desktop.

However, when I launch the url from the shortcut created on the android desktop, then the URL is started from the standard android brower, not from Chrome??

With my GALAXY S3 it works fine, Chrome is used.
But from the GALAXY S4, it does not!

it does not even ask which browser I want to use.
And I have no means to select "open with..."

Maybe I could from EsExplorer, but where can I find the shortcut?
in which folder are they stored?

thanks
Rod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you selected Always... at the first time when opening url, try this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43135/how-to-change-the-default-application-for-android-tasks/

What i'm try to say is i don't think the problem is with chrome. It's your Android settings. And for the second part i don't think you can access your home screen elements from File Explorer.